# Creating combinations/permutations in python of a boolean list without using ITERTOOLS

Tags: python, permutation

```
l = [True, True , False]
```

Without using `itertools` module.

How do yo create permutations of l in a new `list`

```
newlist = [[True,True,False],[True,True,True], [False,False,True],[False,False,False]....]
```

essentially this is what im trying to do:

```
allorderings = itertools.product ([False, True], repeat = n)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python

Comment: [True, True, True], [False, False, True] and [False, False, False] are not permutations of [True, True, False]

Comment: oh right. thats not called permutations. what do you call different combinations?

Comment: So you want product but your input list wasn't specified correctly. Have a look at the implementation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Answer (score 4):

Use `itertools.permutations`

```
import itertools
l = [True, True , False]
newlist = list(itertools.permutations(l))
```

EDIT: from your question, one of the permutations you need is `(True, True, True)` which is not a permutation at all of the list `l`. This answer gives you permutations of a list in the technical sense and you may have to do extra work to achieve what you show in the question(unless of course that was a typo).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I could think of, would be to iterate over the same list of items thrice and collect only the unique items, like this

```
l = set([True, True, False])
print {(i, j, k) for i in l for j in l for k in l}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.permutations`'s equivalent in pure python from the official [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)?

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

```
>>> import itertools
>>> print list(itertools.permutations([True, True , False], 3))
```

Output

```
[(True, True, False), (True, False, True), (True, True, False), (True, False, True), (False, True, True), (False, True, True)]
```

**OR** try this,

```
>>> def combiList(l):
        if not l:
            return [[]]
        res = []
        for e in l:
            temp = l[:]
            temp.remove(e)
            res.extend([[e] + r for r in combiList(temp)])

        return res


>>> combiList([True, True , False])
[[True, True, False], [True, False, True], [True, True, False], [True, False, True], [False, True, True], [False, True, True]]
>>>
```